# How to copy file to HDFS in case insensitive way

Tags: regex, bash, shell, hadoop, bigdata

I have to copy certain CSV files to HDFS of format
`ABCDWXYZ.csv`viz. `PERSONDETAILS.csv` and I have to copy it to an HDFS directory of name `AbcdWxyz` viz PersonDetails.

Now the problem is I don't have exact HDFS directory name, I get it from the CSV file after trimming it and fire put

```
Hadoop fs -put $localRootDir/$Dir/*.csv $HDFSRootDir/$Dir
```

but it throws an error as there is no such directory in HDFS with all uppercase letter.

Now how can I copy the file to HDFS? Is there a way to make the Hadoop put command case insensitive using regex or natively.
Or is there a way by which I can convert the String to required CamelCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
hadoop fs -find / -iname $Dir -print
```

to get the path name in the correct spelling as it exists in HDFS. Then feed that back into your copy command.

Comment: Getting exception unknown command -find rest all other commands are working -ls, -mkdir etc

Comment: Which version and distribution of Hadoop are you using?

Comment: Ah. It is new in Hadoop 2.7.0.

Comment: If you know the spelling of $HDFSRootDir, you could also just do:
hadoop fs -ls $HDFSRootDir | grep -i $Dir.